# Problem $10$, section $4.5$ in Basic Algebra $1$ - Jacobson (Vol I)

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Problem statement:

> Use the method of proof of Artin's lemma to prove that if $y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}$ are real analytic functions which satisfy a linear differential equation $y^{(n)} + a_1 y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_n y = 0$, with constant coefficients $a_i \in \mathbb R$, then the $y_i$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb R$.

The proof of Artin's lemma can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386626/intuition-for-artins-lemma).

I am not seeing how the method can be employed.

I proceeded as follows.

By the given, the system:

$$\begin{cases} \sum_{i=0}^n y_1 ^{(n-i)}(t) x_i = 0 \\ \sum_{i=0}^n y_2 ^{(n-i)}(t) x_i = 0\\ \cdots \\ \sum_{i=0}^n y_{n+1} ^{(n-i)}(t) x_i = 0 \end{cases}$$

has a non-trivial solution for every $t \in \mathbb R$. Hence if we let:

$$A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} y_1^{(n)}(t) & y_1^{(n-1)}(t) & \cdots & y_1(t) \\ y_2^{(n)}(t) & y_2^{(n-1)}(t) & \cdots & y_2(t) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ y_{n+1}^{(n)}(t) & y_{n+1}^{(n-1)}(t) & \cdots & y_{n+1}(t) \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $A(t)$ is singular for all $t$. Hence the matrix obtained from it by reflecting in the mirror then transposing is singular as well. This matrix is:

$$B(t) = \begin{pmatrix} y_1(t) & y_2(t) & \cdots & y_{n+1}(t) \\ y_1'(t) & y_2'(t) & \cdots & y_{n+1}'(t) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ y_1^{(n)}(t) & y_2^{(n)}(t) & \cdots & y_{n+1}^{(n)}(t) \end{pmatrix}$$

hence for all $t \in \mathbb R$, there exists a non-trivial solution of the system $B(t)X = 0$. So there are functions $a_i(t)$ such that for all $t$:

$$\begin{cases} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(t)y_i(t) = 0 \\ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(t)y_i'(t) = 0\\ \cdots \\ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(t)y_i^{(n)}(t) = 0 \end{cases}$$

And for each $t \in \mathbb R$, there exists at least one $i$ such that $a_i(t) \neq 0$. It now remains to either prove that the $a_i$ are constant or to extract from this system a constant solution which works for all $t$. I'm stuck.

Comment: The statement in yellow isn't what you meant.

Comment: @reuns what else?

Comment: Read it again then compare with your system of equations. And why not try replacing $y(t)$ by $e^{s t}$ ?

Comment: @reuns I read it again and I see nothing wrong. Why am I allowed to replace $y(t)$ by $e^{st}$? Also what can that be useful for?

Comment: @reuns I didn't say that the system is equivalent to the given, just that the given implies this.

Comment: Come on... What you meant is : given a linear (homogeneous) differential equation $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k y^{(k)} = 0$ then the solution space is a vector space of dimension at most $n$. It becomes obvious when you look at $e^{st}$.

Comment: At the beginning of your attempted solution, you say "By the given, the system... has a non-trivial solution for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$." Well, isn't the solution just $(x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = (1,a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$, for every $t$?

Comment: Would this statement be true without the assumption that the $y_i$ are real analytic? Perhaps you should think of the linear differential equation as a recursion relation on the coefficients of the Taylor series of the $y$'s.

Comment: @ZachTeitler yes it is, but the point is that a solution exists, so the matrix of coefficients is singular, from which we deduce the existence of a solution of the latter system. Regardless what solution of the first system we started with, we don't know what solution we end up with for the latter system is.

Comment: @ZachTeitler this reduces the system to a system of sequences rather than functions. Maybe then some minimality argument works. I'll see where I can get.